# Disable Button when end of Array is reached

Tags: c#, arrays, button, unity-game-engine

How do I disable a button within a `GameObject` correctly? My code thus far is returning the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object LoadGallery.nextImage ().

This error is coming from the line:

```
Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
```

I don't understand why the reference isn't valid. Also is there a best practice in consolidating the repetitive code in the if-else statement to a single location?

```
// Increment through gallery
if(currentIndexArray < galleryImages.Length)
{
    StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndexArray++);
}
// Disable Next Button when the end is reached
if(currentIndexArray == galleryImages.Length)
{
    GameObject nextBtn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NextBtn");
    Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.enabled = false;
    btn.interactable = false;
}
else
{
    GameObject nextBtn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NextBtn");
    Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.enabled = true;
    btn.interactable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes are zero indexed, so you have to change

```
if(currentIndexArray < galleryImages.Length)
```

To

```
if(currentIndexArray < galleryImages.Length - 1)
```

And

```
if (currentIndexArray == galleryImages.Length)
```

To

```
if (currentIndexArray == galleryImages.Length - 1)
```

Comment: That edit doesn't seem to effect the current issue I'm having with disabling the Button. The error I'm getting is tied back to the instance of btn.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `nextBtn`gameObject is not null before using method `GetComponent<Button>()` on it.

Try adding a null check like this:

```
GameObject nextBtn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NextBtn");
if(nextBtn != null)
{
    Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.enabled = true;
    btn.interactable = true;
}
```

Comment: That was problem. They were null. I put the solution that worked for me just above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by making the button gameObjects public:

```
public GameObject nextBtn;
public GameObject prevBtn;
```

Then I dropped the gameObjects into their respective fields in the script section of Unity's Inspector window. After that I removed the FindObjectByTag lines in my functions and everything else worked.

```
public void nextImage()
{
    // Increment through gallery
    if(currentIndexArray < galleryImages.Length)
    {
        StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndexArray++);
        Debug.Log(currentIndexArray);
    }
    // Disable Next Button when the end is reached
    if(currentIndexArray == galleryImages.Length)
    {
        Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.enabled = false;
        btn.interactable = false;
    } else {
        Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.enabled = true;
        btn.interactable = true;
    }
}

public void prevImage()
{
    // Decrement through gallery
    if(currentIndexArray > 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndexArray--);
        Debug.Log(currentIndexArray);
    }
    // Disable Prev Button when the end is reached
    if(currentIndexArray == 0)
    {
        Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.enabled = false;
        btn.interactable = false;
    } else {
        Button btn = nextBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.enabled = true;
        btn.interactable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can directly Expose Button instead of GameObject and you do not need to get Button Component every time. Edited Answer.

Comment: I think I can tell from the fix, what caused the older bug: You were calling the method before the "Start" method of the next button had been called. So the find my name was returning null.